# How to verify if the Redis instance you are connected to is using encryption?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

AWS Elasticache is offering as a feature encryption In-Transit and At-Rest.

I would like to know if there is way to verify through a client if the Redis cluster you are connected to is using At-Rest Encryption and/or In-Transit Encryption.

It seems logical that the client would know about In-Transit, but I would like to know if it is possible to verify both using the most common Java Redis client libraries.

The feature that I have in mind would require safe temporary storage for caching some data, and if an encrypted Redis instance is not available the intention is to fall back to something else, or prompt a warning that the storage might be unsafe for the data being stored.

Comment: data in transit would be encrypted if communication is over SSL and data at rest will only be encrypted if you are putting data as encrypted

Comment: If you are unsure if the data store is secure, treat it like it isn't. I am not sure if Redis has built-in support for encryption at rest, but if you need to securely store something temporarily, encrypt it yourself before you store it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do Redis Data encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312113/how-to-do-redis-data-encryption)

Comment: AWS Elasticache is providing At-Rest and In-Transit encryption. We were thinking of using that but would have liked to know if there is a way to detect if the instance is using one or both of this settings from the client side.

Comment: @TheDude I am sorry but my question is about detecting if this features are "turned-on" from the client which is supposed to use it. I really do not think my question is a duplicate of the one you pointed out.

Comment: You should refer this question to AWS' support team

Comment: @le-doude I'm currently encountering this scenario. Were you able to find answers to this? If not, what was your workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For In-Transit Encryption, you could try to connect with a client (Jedis for example) that has ssl option disabled. If it could not connect, try ssl option enable. If first try failed, and second try succeeded, that means In-Transit Encryption is in place.

For At-Rest Encryption, the only way I'm aware of is using AWS SDK to describe the cluster and see if the field is true. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticache/describe-cache-clusters.html (This also would help on In-Transit Encryption).